# Backbone.. Link Triggers

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to click on a link and have my JS to find out which link has been clicked

```
<ul>
            <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
```

so when "1" is clicked, from my js file, I want to know which link was clicked..

my.js

```
events : {
                //my click event to call clickedFunction
            },

clicked: function(e){  // if 1 is clicked, go to page 1, if 2 is clicked, go to page 2..}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uyevih/34/edit)

first add an id to your UL so we can find it among other ULs

```
   <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
```

then

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({

  el : $('#list'),              // map the view to your list

  initialize: function(){
    console.log('started');
  },

  events : {
      "click li" : "clicked"   // add an event listener
  },

  clicked: function(val){      // create a callback to the event
     alert("clicked " + val);  
  }
});

window.app = new view();
​
```